# Can this Boolean expression be simplified any further using the commutative law?

Tags: logic

$AB' + B'A + CDE + C'DE + EC'D$
Since $AB' = B'A$:
$AB' + CDE + C'DE + EC'D$
Since $C'DE = EC'D$:
$AB' + CDE + C'DE$
Is this as far as it can be simplified according to  commutative law?

Answer (score 1):

Using only commutativity? Yes. However, distributivity gives us $$AB'+CDE+C'DE=AB'+(C+C')DE,$$ from which we can simplify it slightly further.